# why array.length showing false result.... with variable "name"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i m just learning es 6 and i just socked when... i run this code..

> var name = ["Rahul","Ritika","Amit","Radhika"];
>   console.log(name.length);

the answer is 25.. 25 why?
it must have the answer 4 but gives 25 i don't know why?

i just run the code in browser console the answer is same... 25

but when i change the name of the variable name to something else like "c_name" it works fine...

> let c_name = ["Rahul","Ritika","Amit","Radhika"];
>   console.log(c_name.length);

when i m trying to execute this code the out is again miss behaving...

> // with name varible let name = ["Rahul","Ritika","Amit","Radhika"];
>   for(let i = 0 ; i < name.length; i++)   console.log(name[i]);

```
****output****
"Rahul"
"Ritika"
"Amit"
"Radhika"
```

> // other variable let c_name = ["Rahul","Ritika","Amit","Radhika"];
>   for(let i = 0 ; i < c_name.length; i++)   console.log(c_name[i]);
>    ***output***

```
"R"
"a"
"h"
"u"
"l"
","
"R"
"i"
"t"
"i"
"k"
"a"
","
"A"
"m"
"i"
"t"
","
"R"
"a"
"d"
"h"
"i"
"k"
"a"
```

[for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87369.png)

[Output with name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Res.png)

[Output with c_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL60r.png)

Comment: [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a pre-defined property that can only contain a string value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`name is a property on window object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

If you run your code other than the global scope, it will give you the correct result. The following code example shows that how to do that using[`IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
(function(){ 
  var name = ["Rahul","Ritika","Amit","Radhika"];  
  console.log(name.length);
})();
```